# What were the downstairs gates at ALB used for?

Tags: airport

I was recently traveling through ALB and I noticed two downstairs areas with small gates that looked like they had not been used for a while, can anyone tell me what they were for?

Comment: My first guess would be for small planes not using jetbridges. Seen that (and used them, rarely) at other airports.